# .h instance variable declaration

Tags: objective-c, xcode, controller, declaration

I'm having a hard time understanding why the following textfield is declared twice in some tutorials.

In the .h file:

```
# include <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MyViewController : UIViewController {

    UITextField *name;  // <----- What do I need this for? Is it the same as below?
}

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITextField *name;  // <----- Same as this?

@end
```

At first I thought this would be something like an instance variable, but they are only declared here in the .m file, right?

.m file

```
#import "MyViewController.h"

@implementation UIViewController {

    NSString *myString; // <----- This is an instance variable, right?

}
```

What's the "UITextField *name;" for? Don't I only need the second one with the @property in front? Thank you.

Comment: From Apple Doc (Encapsulating Data):

**You Can Define Instance Variables without Properties**

It’s best practice to use a property on an object any time you need to keep track of a value or another object.

If you do need to define your own instance variables without declaring a property, you can add them inside braces at the top of the class interface or implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an old way, just use property is OK.
If you declare both, you must use @synthesize name; in your .m file to make self.name same as name.
XCode4.2 auto synthesize name = _name. So use self.name as much as possible in your .m file.

Variable in {} just use for internal or private, when you don't want implement setter and getter.

Answer (score 1):

If you are targeting  iPhone OS or 64-bit Mac OS X then you do not need to define ivars for your properties.  Take a look at [Dynamic ivars: solving a fragile base class problem](http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2010/03/dynamic-ivars-solving-fragile-base.html)